# How to replace value with the data-attribute on form submit? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have input text field displays staff name on the form. That field also has data-staff attribute for staff ID. In data base I want to store staff ID instead of staff name. I use JQuery ajax to submit the form. When I check my parameters in debugging tools I see only values for each field what is expected. I was wondering if I can somehow replace value for staff input field with data attribute? Or if there is better way to handle this situation? Here is my example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="frm_staff" id="frm_staff" value="John, Miller" data-staff="052667" size="40" maxlength="50" />
```

JQuery:

```
formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/myFunction.cfc?method='+frmID,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS === 200){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

If anyone knows better technique for this case please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a hidden input with the staff id as value and only display name as text? Seems like user could try to edit name...which would be useless if you override it

Comment: I was thinking about that option. Seems messy adding another field to the form but I can't see better way of doing it so far.

Comment: But it's not "another field" ...it's simply using the field you have to do what you want without having to manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the `value` of your input, using `$('#frm_staff').val()` and [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method, before serializing the form.

Your code would look like this:

```
$('#frm_staff').val($('#frm_staff').data('staff'));
formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize();
```

Comment: if I use this method name value will be replaced with an ID before I submit the form...

Comment: I assume that you are calling this code in the form submit event, isn't it?

Comment: @espresso_coffee if that is not what is expected then question and objective is not clear...neither is higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I do call thin on form submit. but my formData variable is set before the ajax call. I don't understand what is not clear. Let me know I will explain if necessary. Thank you.